# Continued Fraction of a Rational Number

Tags: code-golf, math, rational-numbers

The [**continued fraction**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction) of a number `n` is a fraction of the following form:
[image]
which converges to `n`.

The sequence `a` in a continued fraction is typically written as: [a<sub>0</sub>; a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, a<sub>3</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>].

Your goal is to return the continued fraction of the given rational number (positive or negative), whether it is an:

- integer `x`
- fraction `x/y`
- decimal `x.yz`

**Input**

May be a string representation, or numbers. For fractions, it may be a string, or some native data type for handling fractions, but you may not take it as a decimal.

**Output**

May be a delimited list or string of the *convergents* (the resulting numbers). The output **does not have to have a semi-colon** between a<sub>0</sub> and a<sub>1</sub>, and may use a comma instead.

Note that although `[3; 4, 12, 4]` and `[3; 4, 12, 3, 1]` are [both correct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Finite_continued_fractions), only the first will be accepted, because it is simpler.

#### Examples:

```
860438      [860438]
3.245       [3; 4, 12, 4]
-4.2        [-5; 1, 4]
-114.7802   [-115; 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 4]
0/11        [0]
1/42        [0; 42]
2/7         [0; 3, 2]
-18/17056   [-1; 1, 946, 1, 1, 4]
-17056/18   [-948; 2, 4]
```

#### Rules

- Shortest code wins.
- Built-ins are allowed, but I'd also like you to post in the same answer what it would be without built-ins, so that you have to know how to do it.

Comment: Related: [Determining the continued fractions of square roots](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6401/determining-the-continued-fractions-of-square-roots)

Comment: Can the input be required to be a fraction/rational type (which would require inputting the decimal `3.245` as `3245/1000` or similar)?

Comment: Mathematica wins >:|

Comment: What if there are several solutions? Is `'3'    '2'    '3'    '-6'` acceptable for `3.245`? Also, are leading `0` convergents accepted?

Comment: @LuisMendo What method is used to find alternate solutions? The program I created only finds positive convergents.

Comment: @mbomb007 I use a Matlab function which produces negative ones. But I think the standard represwentation requires positive ones except for possibly the first

Comment: @LuisMendo Just positive only would be great, since that's easier for me to verify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>16</s> <s>13</s> 12 bytes

```
:;ç%@¥@⁶Ṗ¤%?
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=OjvDpyVAwqVA4oG24bmWwqQlPw&input=&args=LTE4+MTcwNTY)

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby, <s>45</s> <s>43</s> 46 bytes

```
f=->n{x,y=n.to_r.divmod 1;[x,*y==0?[]:f[1/y]]}
```

Accepts input as a string.

All test cases pass:

```
llama@llama:~$ for n in 860438 3.245 -4.2 -114.7802 0/11 1/42 2/7 -18/17056 -17056/18; do ruby -e 'f=->n{x,y=n.to_r.divmod 1;[x,*y==0?[]:f[1/y]]}; p f["'$n'"]'; done
[860438]
[3, 4, 12, 4]
[-5, 1, 4]
[-115, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 4]
[0]
[0, 42]
[0, 3, 2]
[-1, 1, 946, 1, 1, 4]
[-948, 2, 4]
```

Thanks to [Kevin Lau](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/kevin-lau-not-kenny) for 2 bytes!

Comment: It hurts, to be beaten by 5 minutes and with a better solution in the same language... Hadn't thought of `n%1`, have a +1

Comment: At any rate, here's a tip for you: `a<<n.floor` should save you 2 bytes.

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny Oh hey I learned a thing!

Comment: `Rational("3.245")` is not allowed, you need to include `Rational` in the code as the OP requested on my answer.

Comment: Correct. The internal representation of a rational is as a numerator and a denominator, so this wouldn't count as handling decimal. As a user, I would want to literally be able to pass the decimals or their string representations in the examples as the input.

Comment: @mbomb007 Fixed, input is now a string.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, <s>50</s> 48 bytes

I noticed @Doorknob♦ beat me to a Ruby answer right before posting, and theirs is also shorter! As such this is just here for posterity now. Takes in a string or an integer (floats have rounding issues, so decimal values need to be put in as strings)

```
f=->s{s=s.to_r;[s.floor]+(s%1!=0?f[1/(s%1)]:[])}
```

Comment: `s.floor` -> `s.to_i` should save a byte.

Comment: @Doorknob♦ It won't. `floor` rounds towards `-∞` while `to_i` truncates towards 0, so the negative test cases give the wrong results.

Answer (score 3):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), 7 bytes

```
ᶦ{1%ŗ}k
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFZtJJurlLsgqWlJWm6FqsebltWbah6dHpt9pLipORiqPCCmx4WZgYmxhZcxkYmpvqGBgYGXLomRkAGl66hoYm5hYERWNCAy0Df0JDLUN_EiMtI3xwoaaFvaG5gagZkgSh9QwuIgQA)

A port of [@Parcly Taxel's Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260825/9288).

```
ᶦ{1%ŗ}k
ᶦ{   }        Iterate the following function until it fails
  1%            Modulo 1
    ŗ           Reciprocal
      k       Floor
```

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 52 bytes

```
f=(n,d)=>n%d?[r=Math.floor(n/d),...f(d,n-r*d)]:[n/d]
```

Accepts numerator and denominator and returns an array, e.g. `f(-1147802, 1e4)` returns `[-115, 4, 1, 1, 4, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 4]`.

Comment: What... `f=(n,d)=>` is allowed??

Comment: @KennyLau That's a lambda.

Comment: I mean, it is allowed to only take fraction?

Comment: @KennyLau Input may be as a string or numbers, but not a decimal. So that was the best that I could do.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 29 bytes

```
`t1e7*Yo5M/kwy-t1e-5>?-1^T}xF
```

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YHQxZTcqWW81TS9rd3ktdDFlLTU-Py0xXlR9eEY&input=LTExNC43ODAy)

This works by repeatedly rounding and inverting (which I think is what Doorknob's answer does too). There may be numerical issues due to using floating point, but it works for all the test cases.

```
`         % Do...while
  t       %   Duplicate. Takes input implicitly the first time
  1e7*    %   Multiply by 1e7
  Yo      %   Round
  5M/     %   Divide by 1e7. This rounds to the 7th decimal, to try to avoid
          %   numerical precision errors
  k       %   Round
  w       %   Swap top two elements of stack
  y       %   Copy the secomnd-from-bottom element
  -       %   Subtract
  t       %   Duplicate
  1e-5>   %   Is it greater than 1e-5? (1e-5 rather than 0; this is again to 
          %   try to avoid numerical precision errors)          
  ?       %   If so
    -1^   %     Compute inverse
    T     %     Push true as loop condition (to start a new iteration)
  }       %   Else
    xF    %     Delete and push false (to exit loop)
          %   End if implicitly
          % End do...while implicitly
          % Display implicitly
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java, <s>85</s> 83 bytes

```java
String f(int n,int d){return n<0?"-"+f(2*(d+n%d)-n,d):n/d+(n%d<1?"":","+f(d,n%d));}
```

#### Takes integer or fraction or decimal as String, 311 bytes

```java
String c(String i){try{return""+Integer.decode(i);}catch(Exception e){int o=i.indexOf(46);if(o>=0)return c((i+"/"+Math.pow(10,i.length()-o-2)).replaceAll("\\.",""));String[]a=i.split("/");int n=Integer.decode(a[0]),d=Integer.decode(a[1]);return n<0?"-"+c(2*(d+n%d)-n+"/"+d):n%d<1?""+n/d:n/d+","+c(d+"/"+(n%d));}}
```

#### Sample input/output:

```java
860438
860438

3.245
3,4,12,4

-4.2
-5,1,4

-114.7802
-115,4,1,1,4,1,1,5,1,1,4

0/11
0

1/42
0,42

2/7
0,3,2

-18/17056
-1,1,946,1,1,4

-17056/18
-948,2,4
```

#### Actual input/output from full program:

```java
860438
860438
860438
860438
860438
3.245
3,4,12,4
3,4,12,4
3,4,12,4
3,4,12,4
-4.2
-5,1,4
-5,1,4
-5,1,4
-5,1,4
-114.7802
-115,4,1,1,4,1,1,5,1,1,4
-115,4,1,1,4,1,1,5,1,1,4
-115,4,1,1,4,1,1,5,1,1,4
-115,4,1,1,4,1,1,5,1,1,4
0/11
0
0
0
0
1/42
0,42
0,42
0,42
0,42
2/7
0,3,2
0,3,2
0,3,2
0,3,2
-18/17056
-1,1,946,1,1,4
-1,1,946,1,1,4
-1,1,946,1,1,4
-1,1,946,1,1,4
-17056/18
-948,2,4
-948,2,4
-948,2,4
-948,2,4
```

#### Full program (including ungolfed functions):

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Q79483 {
    String cf_ungolfed(String input){
        try{
            int result = Integer.parseInt(input);
            return Integer.toString(result);
        }catch(Exception e){
            if(input.indexOf('.')>=0){
                int numerator = Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll("\\.",""));
                int denominator = (int) Math.pow(10, input.length()-input.indexOf('.')-1);
                return cf_ungolfed(numerator+"/"+denominator);
            }
            int numerator = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0,input.indexOf('/')));
            int denominator = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(input.indexOf('/')+1));
            if(numerator%denominator == 0){
                return Integer.toString(numerator/denominator);
            }
            if(numerator < 0){
                return "-"+cf_ungolfed((denominator-numerator+(denominator+2*(numerator%denominator)))+"/"+denominator);
            }
            return (numerator/denominator) + "," + cf_ungolfed(denominator+"/"+(numerator%denominator));
        }
    }
    String c(String i){try{return""+Integer.decode(i);}catch(Exception e){int o=i.indexOf(46);if(o>=0)return c((i+"/"+Math.pow(10,i.length()-o-2)).replaceAll("\\.",""));int n=Integer.decode(i.split("/")[0]),d=Integer.decode(i.split("/")[1]);return n<0?"-"+c(2*(d+n%d)-n+"/"+d):n%d<1?""+n/d:n/d+","+c(d+"/"+(n%d));}}
    String f_ungolfed(int numerator,int denominator){
        if(numerator%denominator == 0){
            return Integer.toString(numerator/denominator);
        }
        if(numerator < 0){
            return "-"+f_ungolfed((denominator-numerator+(denominator+2*(numerator%denominator))),denominator);
        }
        return (numerator/denominator) + "," + f_ungolfed(denominator,(numerator%denominator));
    }
    String f(int n,int d){return n<0?"-"+f(2*(d+n%d)-n,d):n/d+(n%d<1?"":","+f(d,n%d));}
    public static int[] format(String input){
        if(input.indexOf('.') != -1){
            int numerator = Integer.parseInt(input.replaceAll("\\.",""));
            int denominator = (int) Math.pow(10, input.length()-input.indexOf('.')-1);
            return new int[]{numerator,denominator};
        }
        if(input.indexOf('/') != -1){
            int numerator = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0,input.indexOf('/')));
            int denominator = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(input.indexOf('/')+1));
            return new int[]{numerator,denominator};
        }
        return new int[]{Integer.parseInt(input),1};
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            String input = sc.next();
            System.out.println(new Q79483().cf_ungolfed(input));
            System.out.println(new Q79483().c(input));
            int[] formatted = format(input);
            System.out.println(new Q79483().f_ungolfed(formatted[0], formatted[1]));
            System.out.println(new Q79483().f(formatted[0], formatted[1]));
        }
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't catch errors, throw them.

Comment: Why is each test case output four times?

Comment: @mbomb007 Because I called four functions. Look at the last few lines of the full program.

Comment: @mbomb007 Done.

Answer (score 2):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 43 bytes

*-4 from alephalpha*

```
Floor@NestWhileList[1/t&,#,(t=#~Mod~1)>0&]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYq9CoMwFEZfJSBICyn33hg1i8WpU1u6dRAHaSMG/AG9W6mvniadzvkO39TxYKeO3avzfeUv47Ks9d1u/BzcaK9u44aAU5nIA1fJflveOx3PmLapf6xu5qaH@mMK1JmRIlM6B0JEKU5aBQsk0qVB9c9hIxBJQaCVFArKeDBAJeZF1Egg8239Dw)

Comment: Glad to see when someone answers on an old question of mine.

Comment: `Floor@NestWhileList[1/t&,#,(t=#~Mod~1)>0&]&`

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 15 bytes

```
M+]/GH?J%GHgHJY
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=M%2B%5D%2FGH%3FJ%25GHgHJYg.*&input=-18%2C17056&debug=0) (The `g.*` at the end is to fetch the input.)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 107 chars, 214 bytes

```
dd←{⍵=0:0⋄0>k←1∧÷⍵:-k⋄k}⋄nn←{1∧⍵}⋄f←{⍵=0:0x⋄m←⎕ct⋄⎕ct←0⋄z←{0=(d←dd⍵)∣n←nn⍵:n÷d⋄r←⌊n÷d⋄r,∇d÷n-r×d}⍵⋄⎕ct←m⋄z}
```

The function of the exercise f, should have as input one rational number (where 23r33 means as "23/33" in math)
...The algo is the same of the one Neil posted as JavaScript solution... test

```
  f 860438r1
860438 
  f 3245r1000
3 4 12 4 
  f ¯42r10
¯5 1 4 
  f ¯1147802r10000
¯115 4 1 1 4 1 1 5 1 1 4 
  f 0r11
0 
  f 1r42
0 42 
  f 2r7
0 3 2 
  f ¯18r17056
¯1 1 946 1 1 4 
  f ¯17056r18
¯948 2 4 
  f 17056r¯18
¯948 2 4  
  f 18r¯17056
¯1 1 946 1 1 4 
  f 123r73333333333333333333333333373
0 596205962059620596205962059 1 16 1 1 3 
  +∘÷/f 123r73333333333333333333333333373
123r73333333333333333333333333373
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 46 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,d:[n//d]+(n%d*[0]and f(d,n-n//d*d))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P802JzE3KSVRIU8nxSo6T18/JVZbI081RSvaIDYxL0UhTSNFJ08XJK6Voqn5v6AoM69EI03D2MjEVEfB0MDAQFOTCyaoa2hoYm5hYASRAMr8BwA)

Port of [Neil's javascript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/79490/87681)

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 72 bytes

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BasMwEETv@opFYFjVMpFdlxYTB0ohkHPoqfSgWlJQcddBVgol5NsVC9@6MIeZ92DnQY86TV/fdojwNlH0dLFmH/QQ/URXxn71CK7DA0W5RPS7YwyeTtAnJGmW7h3SVgle8dJh84CmpMKIKkM7zhZoY0rMUmG2teA8j1xm2chsigRgrIMf7Ql1OM0dvIag/z7WR5@ig3fyEXq4MljuvKxxJHT42LRPEmqllBD/UFXX7fOLala88hu7sXQH)

```scala
(n,d)=>if(n<0)"-"+f(2*(d+n%d)-n,d)else n/d+(if(n%d<1)""else","+f(d,n%d))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 222 bytes/75 bytes

### A function that takes a string, 222 bytes

```cs
(a,o)=>{var@b=$"{a}/1".Split("/");var@c=$"{b[0]}.0".Split(".");int@n=int.Parse(c[0]),m=int.Parse(c[1]),d=1,r;for(;d<m;d*=10);for(n=n*d+(n>0?1:-1)*m,d*=int.Parse(b[1]);d>0;(n,d)=(d,n-r*d))o.Add(r=(int)Math.Floor(1m*n/d));};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZPdbpswFMevw1NYqBd2Zj5MIElHyFpNjbSp1Sb1YhdVLgi4jdXEtODsQ8hPsds93V4kOwaWrAtSpRAb/3/n7@NzTFY5WSX2l5kShZxVqhTygaJrUalZzjOxTTfzOVqgBO1xSguSzOuvaXmxSs7sOtUes93bp41Q2PZsEhslM8rqzl9q1z@ILohCqguZwL/7OS0rjjNgCN2@WGGwkieMlvF9UeI4n23jfJgwnzTvMpHD/A2Wc/8de@swMtxSUI/xKxMf53M/xpLmJME5lU45zAkp3Ms8x2WCASY3qVq7i00Bjmw7lB7osY73kDxSvFLv04pXcF7JvyHc1gN9kBR11bhbok87RWCorQG2p2M/HE1t2uBHpG7XNaEGGrlBGJ0yI4pCilgAQwc6oRucck4E1D8QY6E7mfp9JGNRa9pG/J1Eh5XOw/cYOw33O5V5YY@5D@FBRwTepBeAIwWHNKcem/jRuC/NJpnzcPx/Xk4T4bGeiiLnPJyCPcCooXVsWXAteJqtETbdw6ZNpjlIyGMriQWNUuUPawDjwHBl190XlxyTGORF41E2c4MWj8CCpXvLn3dcZvzqeZducAuIe4SLRwIz4zz4UgrFr4Xk@Mz@/esnqsHKYZG@q9tb5H4shMRwMNvsoJd2Y6Lh4ZuK97ksXvVAuE8xNdBLctgAflmqsjW@@p7xJ/OhI07aevRvV3P3hldV@sD16ztoS@//AA)

### Just the part that takes numerator and denominator, 75 bytes

```cs
(n,d,o)=>{for(int@r;d>0;(n,d)=(d,n-r*d))o.Add(r=(int)Math.Floor(1m*n/d));};
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZTfb9owEMefyV9xiibVhvwyDZQuha2airSJapP6sIeKhzRxwWrqtIlpN6H8FXvdX7d/hJ2dAGvJVAnh5O5zX9/5fElKNynF5jxRIpdnQioHzN9MlOos5Ym4j7PJBKYwhg2RTurkdDxZ3@YFQexjEaWTINJ2OiapI92im1Kae@dpSoqxRuhlrJbeNMsxgt13pY/@qIo2T7lIYbpakFIVQi4gfrUl5NRaWx1V/LQ6uHamWsz7FhclJzF1gDlIRFansjpJrJJlTRncPHWe4gJuMOvYu3rIhCK2b2v@pdLNdTCnpuKdgWmDkdbaW/H/aHqNpnZk6NDh3ozLhVru7BLtzLzhqYHeHASaggiXM8gi6PUERaqLWNCeIXTR3wPzgj8Yj@HIPYIP4DJ4D0z7D0qQ/1RRWZVl6VwUL9WnuOQlJiD5M2xP/zPSzclfz@HrSlFcsGRij4ZBeDyyHYPvkXVtr6ijoWOvHw4OmWMHQuxUH5cGdEOvf8i5A9PPHcRY6J2MgjaSsUEtWkdsHwY7S6MR@IwdhgeNl/lhi3iA4f2G6PsnrQCW1N@lOfLZSTAYtqVpkjkNh6/zck2Ez1pOFNzTcITyCIOhq8iy8MrwOFkC0d0juk26OdjtfStfzonmiqa7LwaKmMugJ06rFOZNw/kd0ijqXfHHFZcJv3hcxRmpAXELJL@j2/v/vRCKz4Tk5J395/cvWKOUywbV9bq@R96XXEiCpdl6h2pu78aIZyVvU5m@qQGkzaNPoZpTe3/D60klFz8S/qC/ZcBpfSLt2625d8nLMl7w6u0dcH42fwE)

### Un-golfed code:

```cs
(input, output) =>
{
	var fracStr = $"{input}/1".Split("/"); // append "/1" so we never get an array out of bounds
	var decStr = $"{fracStr[0]}.0".Split("."); // append ".0" so we never get an array out of bounds

	// parse the decimal number first,
	// if we weren't passed a decimal, m will be 0
	int n = int.Parse(decStr[0]);
	int m = int.Parse(decStr[1]);
	int d = 1;

	// denominator will be the next power of 10 larger than m:
	for (; d < m; d *= 10);

	// scale the numerator by the denominator, and add the decimal part:
	n = n * d + (n > 0 ? 1 : -1) * m;

	// now handle the fraction case
	// if we weren't passed a fraction then fracStr[1] will be "1"
	// if we were passed a fraction, d will be 1
	d *= int.Parse(fracStr[1]);

	// now actually calculate the continued fraction:
	for (; d > 0; )
	{
		int r = (int)Math.Floor(1m * n / d);
		output.Add(r);
		(n, d) = (d, n - r * d);
	}
};
```